# Почему не срабатывает grep '*\.c$'

Tags: регулярные-выражения, grep, bash, linux

Есть файл 1 со списком файлов в каталоге. Надо найти все с расширением .c.

Вот это работет `cat 1 | grep '\.c$'` - выводит то что нужно. Правда строка ".c" тоже выводится. Как исключить ее из списка?

А если дать такой запрос `cat 1 | grep '*\.c$'`, то не находит ни одного имени. Почему звездочка в начале шаблона все портит? Не должна же по идее.

Для примера в файле есть строка "1234.c". Она точно попадает под описание шаблона, но почему-то вторая команда ее не выводит. На самом деле я не смог еще подобрать такую строку, что бы она подходила.

Почему так?

Comment: Потому, что надо читать документацию по регулярным выражения, прежде чем пытаться их применять.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало!


dzihoev:
Если бы все читали всю документацию и понимали с первого раза, то таких проектов как hashcode.ru не существовало бы.

Comment: @bullvinkle ставте перед никнеймом @ так вы подчернёте что это никнейм...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы используете grep '*.c$', фактически вы ищете точно такую же строчку. ReinRaus привел правильную маску, однако забыл указать что grep по умолчанию не использует регулярные выражения, необходимо использовать опцию '-E':

```
grep -E '.+\.c$' test.txt
```

И по самой маске:

- . - Любой символ
- + Одно или больше повторений предыдущего элемента
- . - точка
- с$ - строчка должна заканчиваться символом 'c'

Comment: Если честно- не пользовался grep :) Просто автор указал корректно работающую у него команду, а я подставил в нее правильное регулярное выражение.

Comment: Лучше даже вот так  

    egrep '.+\.c$' test.txt

Comment: Все работает по

    grep '..*\.c$'

Answer (score 2):

```
grep '[A-z0-9]\.c$'
```

Почитайте ман на эту тему, хотя я что-то тоже не понял почему не работает=)

Answer (score 1):

У меня все работает

```
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent/wtst$ cat li
qt.c 1
.c
gag.c
ywyw
whw.h
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent/wtst$ cat li | grep '.*\.c'
qt.c 1
.c
gag.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent/wtst$ cat li | grep '..*\.c$'
gag.c
avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent/wtst$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS \n \l

avp@avp-xub11:~/src/ig/web-agent/wtst$
```